# How to use fallback value when jq select() returns false

Tags: json, select, jq, default, key-value

Let's say I have a JSON array like this:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "alpha",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "beta",
        "value": 2
    },
    ...
]
```

(It contains about 50-100 items; this is a simplified example.)

I want to produce a JSON object from it like this:

```json
{
  "alpha": 1,
  "beta" 2,
  ...
}
```

I *think* the jq filter for it looks something like this:

```
.[] | { 
  "alpha": select(.name == "alpha") | .value,
  "beta": select(.name == "beta") | .value,
  ...
}
```

That doesn't actually work when I try it on https://jqplay.org/s/SOKd4oCh2k, but I think it's pretty close.

OK now here's the tricky part: sometimes the object with `"name": "alpha"` (or `"name": "beta"`, etc.) won't actually exist in the input array! In that case, I want to print `"alpha": null` or `"alpha": ""`. But I can't figure out how to integrate that into my `select()` call.

In practice I need this to scrape job metrics from a batch scheduling system, where I'm changing the metrics over time as I run performance tests, so any given metric that I'm querying might not exist for a particular job run, but I still want to see all the *other* metrics from that job run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jq-esque solution to the problem is illustrated by:

```
jq 'from_entries | {alpha, beta, gamma}' input.json
```

This will convert the array to an object, and then select the values corresponding to the specified keys if present, while also ensuring all the specified keys are present.

### Keylist

If you have a JSON array of key namess (say $keylist), you could write:

```
from_entries as $in
| reduce $keylist[] as $key ({}; .[$key]=$in[$key])
```

### Fallback value

Or if you want to specify your own fallback value, say $default:

```
from_entries as $in
| reduce $keylist[] as $key ({}; .[$key] = $in[$key] // $default)
```

or perhaps (depending on your detailed requirements):

```
from_entries as $in
| reduce $keylist[] as $key ({};
    .[$key] = if ($in | has($key)) then $in[$key] else $default end)
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome, and it works great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Oh shoot I just realized that `from_entries` won't work for me, because my fields are actually named `"metricName"` and `"doubleValue"`, _not_ `"name"` and `"value"`. I would have included this in my question, but I didn't think the specific field names would matter, so I used "name" and "value" to make my question more generic...

So given that I can't use `from_entries`, is there a more jq-esque solution than this?

 `[.[] | { (.metricName): .doubleValue }] | add | {alpha, beta, gamma}`

Comment: Close! The more jq-esque solution would use `map`: `map( {(.metricName): .doubleValue} ) | add | {alpha,beta,gamma}`

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Works for me: https://jqplay.org/s/lQzCVY0xrA

Answer (score 2):

Of course right after posting this, I figure it out. The solution I came up with is to flatten the array of objects into a single object, using the `add()` function.

So this filter:

```
[.[] | { (.name): .value }] | add
```

produces:

```json
{
  "alpha": 1,
  "beta": 2
}
```

And then to select the individual fields I'm interested in, it's basic object creation; e.g. `| {alpha, beta, gamma}` (where "gamma" is missing from the input array) produces:

```json
{
  "alpha": 1,
  "beta": 2,
  "gamma": null
}
```

In case anyone wants to play around with this: https://jqplay.org/s/vqEYyGCg7W

I'll leave this question open for awhile, in case someone has a better solution!